# Change UILabel Text color in UItableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uilabel

I have a large custom `UITableView` with `UILabels` in each row, and I'd like to display certain texts in Black or Green color.

I feed the cells with the `NSString's` from a `NSArray`. Suppose I want to display in black only the the `NSString` from index `30`.

I'm Trying something like this, but it's not working:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathWithBlackText = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:30 inSection:[indexPath section]];

    if (indexPath.row == indexPathWithBlackText.row) {  
        //Label with text in black 
        topLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        topLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
    } else {
        //Label with text in green 
        topLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.122 green:0.467 blue:0.255 alpha:1.00];
    }
```

Any hints on the right direction will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why dont you do  if (indexPath == indexPathWithBlackText) ? and where in the code are you doing this?

Comment: I'm just trying to distribute the black or green colored text labels to a fixed place, the same as the indexes in the NSArray that feed the cells. The problem is that when I scroll the UITableView other texts change colors too and not only the ones in the rows I'd want too, I think it's due to the UITableView dynamic drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this UITableViewDataSource delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Write this:

```
if ([self isBlackRow:indexPath.row]) {
    // Your label reference, change color to black here.
} else {
    // Your label reference, change color to green here. 
}
```

Make a method to determine if the row is black or not

```
- (BOOL)isBlackRow:(NSInteger)row {
    NSArray* blackRows = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:30], [NSNumber numberWithInt:11], nil];

    for (NSNumber* number in blackRows) {
        if (number.intValue == row) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: It works, but only for row 30. What if I want different rows like 3, 6, 11, 19?

Comment: That will work. I have to figure out a way to make the || statements dynamic, because they may vary and they are coming to me in an NSArray of NSNumbers...

Comment: It works initially, but when I scroll the UITableView other texts change colors too and not only the ones in the rows I'd want too, I think it's due to the UITableView dynamic drawing. Thanks for poing the direction!

Comment: Now it's working fine!!!! I just changed the place here I was doing the drawing of the cell!!!! Thanks a lot you saved the day!!!!

Comment: Just one small detail, instead of : it should be in, on your  for (NSNumber* number : blackRows) iteration. Thanks again!

Comment: @Winston Yes, sorry I was thinking in Java :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (indexPath.row > 29) {  
    //Label with text in black 
    topLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    topLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
} else {
    //Label with text in green 
    topLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.122 green:0.467 blue:0.255 alpha:1.00];
}
```

Comment: It works, but only for row 30. What if I want different rows like 3, 6, 11, 19?

Comment: i think it will be worked rows greater than 30 . is it working for only 30 th row ?

Comment: Yes and the verification provided by Andreas helped to solve the problem for more random rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the labels to the table view?

It may be that you're not referencing the right object.

Comment: The problem is that each time I scroll the UITableView it changes the color of other cells too.